# read all elements of martix diagonally from upper left to lower right

Tags: java

I am having a java code that reads diagonal values from upper right to lower left  , But I want code to read values from upper left to lower right.

```
int [][]mat = { {1,2,3},
                {4,5,6},
                {7,8,9},
};

int N=3;

for (int s=0; s<N; s++) {
    for (int i=s; i>-1; i--) {
        System.out.print(mat[i][s-i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

for (int s=1; s<N; s++) {
    for (int i=N-1; i>=s; i--) {
        System.out.print(mat[i][s+N-1-i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

and output of above code is

1 
  4 2 
  7 5 3 
  8 6 
  9

I want sequence like

```
3 2 6 1 5 9 4 8 7
```

Comment: Then reverse the read direction and change the starting point from 0,0 to 0,2.

Comment: Wouldn't `upper left to lower right` start with `1`?

Comment: `for (int s = N; s > 0; s--) {`

Comment: can you give me code for that sir??

Comment: @XtremeBaumer The OP wants left to right diagonals, starting with the upper left corner.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen "I want sequence like 3 2 6 1 5 9 4 8 7" implies that asker wants to start with the top right, which is confusing as that's different to what he seems to be asking

Comment: I want sequence like 3 2 6 1 5 9 4 8 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int [][]mat = { {1,2,3},
                {4,5,6},
                {7,8,9},
};

int N=3;

for (int s=N-1; s>-N; --s) {
    int iMin = s>0 ? s : 0;
    int iMax = s>0 ? N : N+s;
    for (int i=iMin; i<iMax; ++i) {
        System.out.print(mat[i-s][i] + " ");
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

**Output**

```
3 2 6 1 5 9 4 8 7
```

Comment: Thank you sir but Is print only upper bound matrix only.

Comment: Corrected `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @AishwaryaChavan - What do you mean by "upper bound matrix"? Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Look good now! Tested with a 4x4 and it produced the correct result.

Comment: @user31601 I don't get remaining numbers 4 8 7

Comment: @AishwaryaChavan Did you copy & paste code exactly? As Michael suggested, I have tested it, and it works for me!

Comment: @user31601 yes sir is working, but i get only 3 2 6 1 5 9 this elements

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to achieve the needed output.

```
for (int s = N - 1; s > -1; s--) {
    for (int i = s; i < N; i++) {
        System.out.print(mat[i - s][i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    }

for (int s = 1; s < N; s++) {
   for (int i = s; i < N; i++) {
        System.out.print(mat[i][i - s] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: What did you change? Can you explain the changes? Why didn't it work before?